# Server in Android virtual device not receiving python client connection so it can't get past ServerSocket.accept()

Tags: python, java, android, websocket, android-virtual-device

I'm currently trying to use sockets to send strings from a python client to a server socket inside an android app running in an android virtual device. The server waits at the point it reaches ServerSocket.accept()

```
public class MyServer implements Runnable{ //EXECUTED IN A NEW THREAD
                                         //I'VE INCLUDED THE INTERNET PERMISSION AS WELL
ServerSocket ss;
Socket mySocket;
DataInputStream dis;

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ss=new ServerSocket(5554);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("ALWAYS PRINTS THIS AND GETS STUCK AT THIS POINT");
            mySocket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("NEVER PRINTS THIS");
            dis = new DataInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
            String mensaje = dis.readUTF();  //MORE STUFF NEVER EXECUTED
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //NEVER REACHES THIS POINT EITHER
    }
```

And never goes any further. I've been trying to make it go past this point connecting from the python client with this code:

```
def conSock():
HOST = '127.0.0.1' # Have also tried with the avd's ip 16.0.2.2 and some other ips
PORT = 5554        # Have also tried with 8080, 65321 ,etc

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    print('ALWAYS PRINTS THIS')
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print('NEVER* PRINTS THIS')
    s.sendall(b"Hello World")
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print("Received ", repr(data))
```

But it only seems to go past accept() when I call localhost:5554 from a browser inside the virtual device. I've gotten no error messages in Android but I had errno 10060 and 10061 in Python depending on the IP I used. Recently, I received "Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands" as a response in the Python console but still no response from Android. I have very little experience with sockets and feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: So the server is an Android app running in an emulator? And the client? Where does it run? Scenario please.

Comment: If a client uses 127.0.0.1 it tries to connect to a server running on the same device as it runs itself.

Comment: @blackapps The client runs in the hosting machine

Comment: If you mean that the client runs on the same pc as the emulator is running on then was that the answer i expected.

Comment: What's the ip I should be using in this scenario then?

Answer (score 0):

You better stop trying this. As you need to be a network expert to connect a client running on a pc with a server running in an emulator that runs on the same pc. If you could reverse client and server it was easy to let the client connect. But not in this scenario. No, take a real Android device. Then you can use the local lan ip of the Android device.

Comment: I would use a real Android device if it depended on me but sadly it doesn't.